# How to bind to <progress> element?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
 Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    percentage: 0,
  },
...
```

I want to do `<progress max="100" v-model="percentage"></progress>` but I'm getting `error  'v-model' directives aren't supported on <progress> elements`. How to do it otherwise?

I would like to render it as such (or similar)

```
<progress max="100" value="0"></progress>
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What's the ``prop`` that needs to take the value from the store?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with prop. I have a variable in the Vuex state storing the percentage number.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `v-model="percentage"` with `:value="percentage"` ?

Comment: Using `:value="percentage"` renders `<progress max="100">`. The value attribute is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the parent of the `progress` component;

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";
```

```
computed: {
               ...mapState({
                    percentage: state => state.percentage,
               }),
}
```

This will get the updated values from the store. Then, bind it to the value of the component:

```
<progress max="100" :value="percentage"></progress>
```